# Create sitecore template field with specific condition

Tags: presentation, templates

one specific requirement in which content editor needs to choose properties by state. I have properties with states field. Now I am planning to create the user-defined template for a content editor to choose properties based on the state.

How to add property filtering in template based on the selected state in the drop-down?

Comment: I assume you want to filter a field based on the selected state? If so, with Sitecore OOTB, there is no way to filter fields being displayed based on external factors.

Comment: is it possible to search property name in the template? I tried multi-list with the search but am not getting expected result.

Comment: If I have understood well, you want to have a set of properties available based on the selected state?

Comment: For this particular requirement, if you want to use WFFM or custom form you can try nice article from Sitecore: https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/80/working_with_fields_actions_and_validations/fields/show_or_hide_form_fields_depending_on_other_field_values

Answer (score 1):

For such solutions we used a solution by Dan Cruikshank: https://getfishtank.ca/en/blog/using-item-field-as-a-data-source-in-sitecore

The DataSource of your Dropdown would be the path to your 'states' and the other field will show the filtered 'propterties'.

You first have to select a 'state', save the item and you will get a selection of the available 'properties'.

Hope this helps.